# LaTeX: tikz and chemfig combination

Tags: tex, latex

Yes, I know, I did an (ab) use of the nodes. Is there a better way to make this image with TeX/LaTeX?

Using MiKTeX with Texmaker

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm,headheight=16pt,headsep=0.1in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes}
\setchemfig{%
%       %scheme debug=true,
        arrow offset=9pt,
        arrow coeff=0.7,
%       compound sep=5em,
        + sep left=0.6em,
        + sep right=0.6em,
        atom sep=1.25em,
        fixed length=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        
\node (n-eptane) at (0, 0) {\chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]--[:-30]--[:-30]}};
\draw[-Triangle] (1.75,0)--++(1,0);
\node (n-eptane-cation) at (5.5, 0) {
    \chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]-\charge{90:4pt=$\oplus$}{}-[:-30]--[:-30]}
};
\draw[gray] (3,.5)--++(5,0);
\draw[gray] (3,.75)--++(5,0);
\foreach \i in {3,3.25,3.5,3.75,...,7.75} {
    \draw[gray] (\i,.5)--(\i+0.25,.75);
}
\draw[-Triangle] (8.5,0)--++(1,0);
\node (propane_and_buthane) at (11.25, 0) {
    \chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]} + \chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]-}
};
\draw[gray] (3,-.4)--++(5,0);
\draw[gray] (3,-.65)--++(5,0);
\foreach \i in {3,3.25,3.5,3.75,...,7.75} {
    \draw[gray] (\i,-.65)--(\i+0.25,-.4);
}
        
\node (2-methyl-exane) at (.15, -1.15) {
    \chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]--[:-30](-[:-90])-[:30]}
};
\node (c) at (2, -1.1 + .3) {};
\node (d) at (2, -1.1 - .3) {};
\draw[-Triangle] (c)  to [out=0,in=0,looseness=2] (d);

\draw[gray] (3,-1.5)--++(5,0);
\draw[gray] (3,-1.75)--++(5,0);
\foreach \i in {3,3.25,3.5,3.75,...,7.75} {
    \draw[gray] (\i,-1.75)--(\i+0.25,-1.5);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think the hatched lines could be simplified a bit. Instead of drawing two lines and then all the tiny lines in the for-loop, you could draw a double line and fill it with a hatched pattern:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[gray,double distance=0.25cm] (3,-1.625)--++(5,0);
\fill[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={5pt}]},pattern color=gray] (3,-1.5) rectangle ++(5,-0.25);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And instead of manually calculating all your coordinates, you could position them relative to the nodes you names, e.g. you can position the arrow relative to the `n-eptane` node:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\setchemfig{%
%       %scheme debug=true,
        arrow offset=9pt,
        arrow coeff=0.7,
%       compound sep=5em,
        + sep left=0.6em,
        + sep right=0.6em,
        atom sep=1.25em,
        fixed length=true
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        
\node (n-eptane) at (0, 0) {\chemfig{[:30]--[:-30]--[:-30]--[:-30]}};
\draw[-Triangle] (n-eptane) ++(1.8,0)--++(1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```